# How can I make my sed script run faster?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, performance, large-files

I got this script my a related question of mine - [How do I insert the filename and header to the beginning of a csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57321999/how-do-i-insert-the-filename-and-header-to-the-beginning-of-a-csv-using-sed-awk)

```
find . -name '*.csv' -printf "%f\n" |
sed 's/.csv$//' |
xargs -I{} sed -i '1s/^/customer|/ '$'\n'' 1!s/^/{}|/' {}.csv;
```

Currently for large files it takes quite some time. I scaled it to 50,000 files and got this result.

```
real    1m41.251s
user    0m59.326s
sys     0m38.681s
```

For 100,000 files I got this.

```
real    3m18.466s
user    1m58.451s
sys     1m16.550s
```

`du -sh` for 100,000 files gives 485M. I would like to scale this data up to 10-20 GB.

I would like to know if there is any way to speed up the above script. I'm open to using any tools to speed things up.

If it helps, I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.02 LTS, 16 GB RAM.

---

Using [Ed Morton's answer to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57328092/5675288)

```
time awk -i inplace -v OFS='|' 'FNR==1{cust=FILENAME; sub(/\.csv$/,"",cust)} {print (FNR>1 ? cust : "customer"), $0}' *.csv

real    0m20.253s
user    0m3.336s
sys     0m14.854s
```

It's blazingly faster than the inital `sed` :o. I don't understand why though. If anyone can explain it, it would be really helpful.

---

The above script when I scaled it to a million files, says `Argument list too long`.

I tried the following, but it is slow,

```
find . -name \*.csv -exec awk -i inplace -v OFS='|' 'FNR==1{cust=FILENAME; sub(/\.csv$/,"",cust)} {print (FNR>1 ? cust : "customer"), $0}' {} \;
```

Even if I do it batch wise, it seems slow for 100,000 files.

```
time find . -name "10*.csv" -exec awk -i inplace -v OFS='|' 'FNR==1{cust=FILENAME; sub(/\.csv$/,"",cust)} {print (FNR>1 ? cust : "customer"), $0}' {} \;

real    9m29.474s
user    2m3.336s
sys     6m37.822s
```

I tried the usual for loop using Ed's answer but it seems to work at the same rate as the original files being generated, around 40 minutes for 1 million records.

```
for file in *.csv; do
    echo "$file"
    awk -i inplace -v OFS='|' 'FNR==1{cust=FILENAME; sub(/\.csv$/,"",cust)} {print (FNR>1 ? cust : "customer"), $0}' "$file"
done
```

I tried to batch it using `ls` and `xargs` for every 100,000 files, and this seems reasonable as the initial solution Ed has given.

```
time ls 11*.csv | xargs awk -i inplace -v OFS='|' 'FNR==1{cust=FILENAME; sub(/\.csv$/,"",cust)} {print (FNR>1 ? cust : "customer"), $0}'

real    0m23.619s
user    0m3.537s
sys     0m15.272s

time ls 12*.csv | xargs awk -i inplace -v OFS='|' 'FNR==1{cust=FILENAME; sub(/\.csv$/,"",cust)} {print (FNR>1 ? cust : "customer"), $0}'

real    0m25.044s
user    0m3.892s
sys     0m16.261s

time ls 13*.csv | xargs awk -i inplace -v OFS='|' 'FNR==1{cust=FILENAME; sub(/\.csv$/,"",cust)} {print (FNR>1 ? cust : "customer"), $0}'

real    0m24.997s
user    0m4.035s
sys     0m16.757s
```

What I'm planning now is to use the above solution, use a for loop to batch through. Given an avg of 25 secs for each batch, it'd be over by 25*10 -> 4 mins appx. Which I feel is fast for the million records.

If anyone has a better solution please let me know. If any of the code written above is wrong/bad please let me know. I'm still a beginner and might have copied or understood things improperly.

Comment: Are all these files in a single directory or are there any sub directories within that directory?  Also it may help to explain exactly what your sed commands are doing, The whole xargs command is not obvious to me.

Comment: Reading and writing thousands of files takes time, there's not really any way around that.

Comment: @Barmar: Saving even a fraction of a second per iteration will make a huge difference in the overall runtime especially when there are more files.

Comment: The system time is the time spent reading and writing the files, so you can only optimize the user time. If you improve it by 10%, that's only 12 seconds out of over 3 minutes.

Comment: Try `xargs -P 2` or `-P 4`, it might help with spawning a billion sed processes (write a dedicated tool to avoid & it could perhaps do readahead and other things). Use SSD and/or write to different disk than you read from. Best option would be to not do this post-processing in the first place - what generates this data and what interprets it so you have to add such redundant information? Those are better places to optimize.

Comment: @Barmar: That isn't what system time means but also OP is saying this is just a small test and his real use case will be significantly larger.  Either way any time saved here will scale to even more time saved in the real use case.

Comment: @Jesse_b It's not what it "means", but in something like this it's what it almost certainly mostly involves. `sed` doesn't need to make any other expensive system calls.

Comment: You could use a ramdisk for the fastest I/O, e.g. `sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=2048M tmpfs /media/ramdisk` and do all your modifications in there and then move the files back to your regular filesystem.

Comment: Install gawk and use the final script I posted at https://stackoverflow.com/a/57328092/1745001.

Comment: @Jesse_b went to bed so didn't see what's going on here. To give context, I have a set of files generated, to simulate real world data. Each file contains 1-25 lines excluding header, in the format in the linked question. Only their file names are their identifier. So I would like to add a column name "customer" identifying the customer, and fill the records of that columns with the column - customer unique ID. I will then be merging all the files into one file, before dumping it into my db as staging before I move it around inside the db to normalize it.

Comment: @Jesse_b the dataset is a small subset of a real world data which has already been implemented as a system using hadoop. I'm trying this out as a learning exercise to figure out data modelling, limitations of using a dbms at such scale, why move to hadoop, how to use hadoop, cloud services if possible like aws, and so on. This is just a very small step in the huge learning curve I am taking up.

Comment: @frostschutz starting point of this use case is that the client has a hell lot of excel files lying around. Each excel has info about 1 customer. I didn't want to work with excel so I generated csv. This is a small subset of the actual data. The filenames are the unique identifiers of the customer. They aren't included in the file itself. That's one of the main reason for adding the redundant info. Pls read the comment above for why I'm doing this project. If you feel there is a better way please let me know, I'm willing to learn.

Comment: @Barmar I was afraid this might be a I/O limitation. I would still like to understand if there is an efficient way to do it. I understand that this learning exercise for me, might seem trivial to others, but I would still like to learn as much as possible, figure out limitations, etc.

Comment: @EdMorton I will give this a try and keep you posted.

Comment: wrt `It's blazingly faster than the inital sed` - you don't have an initial sed, you have an initial shell script that calls find + sed + xargs + many-calls-to-sed. For the shell, spinning up all those processes takes time vs creating just 1 process for the awk script.

Comment: @EdMorton Please add your answer here also if you don't mind? I can accept it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -v OFS=',' 'FNR==1{cust=FILENAME; sub(/\.csv$/,"",cust)} {print (FNR>1 ? cust : "customer"), $0}' 10000000.csv
customer,first_name,middle_name,last_name,gender,email,phone_number,address,city,state,country,date_order_start,date_order_complete,invoice_number,invoice_date,item,item_price,quantity,cost,job_name,job_price,total_cost
10000000,Chae,Jesusa,Cummings,Female,deifier2040@example.com,555-555-8750,911 Hauser Pike,Moline,Georgia,Cameroon,2016-06-29,2016-07-16,36298,2016-07-17,Acer,493.86,14,354.77,Broken,123.68,898.13
```

so with any awk you could do:

```
for file in *.csv; do
    awk 'script' "$file" > tmp && mv tmp "$file"
done
```

or with GNU awk for "inplace" editing:

```
$ tail -n +1 10000000.csv 10000001.csv
==> 10000000.csv <==
first_name,middle_name,last_name,gender,email,phone_number,address,city,state,country,date_order_start,date_order_complete,invoice_number,invoice_date,item,item_price,quantity,cost,job_name,job_price,total_cost
Chae,Jesusa,Cummings,Female,deifier2040@example.com,555-555-8750,911 Hauser Pike,Moline,Georgia,Cameroon,2016-06-29,2016-07-16,36298,2016-07-17,Acer,493.86,14,354.77,Broken,123.68,898.13

==> 10000001.csv <==
first_name,middle_name,last_name,gender,email,phone_number,address,city,state,country,date_order_start,date_order_complete,invoice_number,invoice_date,item,item_price,quantity,cost,job_name,job_price,total_cost
Fleta,Rosette,Hurley,Other,tobacconist1857@example.com,1-555-555-1210,35 Freelon Arcade,Beaverton,Rhode Island,Cayman Islands,2009-06-08,2009-06-29,39684,2009-07-01,NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980,474.31,16,395.79,Broken,157.53,1088.04
Bennett,Dennis,George,Male,dona1910@example.com,(555) 555-4131,505 Robert C Levy Arcade,Wellington,Louisiana,Mexico,2019-05-09,2019-05-19,37938,2019-05-21,8GB,187.67,16,205.77,Service,170.21,1007.85
Tommye,Pamula,Diaz,Other,dovelet1967@example.com,555.555.4445,1001 Canby Boulevard,Edinburg,Massachusetts,Gambia,2004-05-02,2004-05-24,31364,2004-05-26,Lenovo,137.21,13,193.63,Replacement,246.43,934.31
Albert,Jerrold,Cohen,Other,bolio2036@example.com,+1-(555)-555-8491,1181 Baden Avenue,Menomonee Falls,Texas,Tajikistan,2019-08-03,2019-08-12,37768,2019-08-15,Intel® Iris™ Graphics 6100,396.46,17,223.02,Service,118.53,960.27
Louetta,Collene,Best,Fluid,dinner1922@example.com,1-555-555-7050,923 Barry Viaduct,Laurel,Illinois,St. Barthélemy,2009-03-02,2009-03-06,39557,2009-03-07,AMD Radeon R9 M395X,133.9,11,198.49,Fix,178.54,1055.32
Kandace,Wesley,Diaz,Female,closterium1820@example.com,+1-(555)-555-5414,341 Garlington Run,Santa Maria,New Jersey,Mexico,2005-10-09,2005-10-10,30543,2005-10-14,Samsung,590.29,5,354.85,Service,292.56,1032.22
```

.

```
$ awk -i inplace -v OFS=',' 'FNR==1{cust=FILENAME; sub(/\.csv$/,"",cust)} {print (FNR>1 ? cust : "customer"), $0}' 10000000.csv 10000001.csv
```

.

```
$ tail -n +1 10000000.csv 10000001.csv
==> 10000000.csv <==
customer,first_name,middle_name,last_name,gender,email,phone_number,address,city,state,country,date_order_start,date_order_complete,invoice_number,invoice_date,item,item_price,quantity,cost,job_name,job_price,total_cost
10000000,Chae,Jesusa,Cummings,Female,deifier2040@example.com,555-555-8750,911 Hauser Pike,Moline,Georgia,Cameroon,2016-06-29,2016-07-16,36298,2016-07-17,Acer,493.86,14,354.77,Broken,123.68,898.13

==> 10000001.csv <==
customer,first_name,middle_name,last_name,gender,email,phone_number,address,city,state,country,date_order_start,date_order_complete,invoice_number,invoice_date,item,item_price,quantity,cost,job_name,job_price,total_cost
10000001,Fleta,Rosette,Hurley,Other,tobacconist1857@example.com,1-555-555-1210,35 Freelon Arcade,Beaverton,Rhode Island,Cayman Islands,2009-06-08,2009-06-29,39684,2009-07-01,NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980,474.31,16,395.79,Broken,157.53,1088.04
10000001,Bennett,Dennis,George,Male,dona1910@example.com,(555) 555-4131,505 Robert C Levy Arcade,Wellington,Louisiana,Mexico,2019-05-09,2019-05-19,37938,2019-05-21,8GB,187.67,16,205.77,Service,170.21,1007.85
10000001,Tommye,Pamula,Diaz,Other,dovelet1967@example.com,555.555.4445,1001 Canby Boulevard,Edinburg,Massachusetts,Gambia,2004-05-02,2004-05-24,31364,2004-05-26,Lenovo,137.21,13,193.63,Replacement,246.43,934.31
10000001,Albert,Jerrold,Cohen,Other,bolio2036@example.com,+1-(555)-555-8491,1181 Baden Avenue,Menomonee Falls,Texas,Tajikistan,2019-08-03,2019-08-12,37768,2019-08-15,Intel® Iris™ Graphics 6100,396.46,17,223.02,Service,118.53,960.27
10000001,Louetta,Collene,Best,Fluid,dinner1922@example.com,1-555-555-7050,923 Barry Viaduct,Laurel,Illinois,St. Barthélemy,2009-03-02,2009-03-06,39557,2009-03-07,AMD Radeon R9 M395X,133.9,11,198.49,Fix,178.54,1055.32
10000001,Kandace,Wesley,Diaz,Female,closterium1820@example.com,+1-(555)-555-5414,341 Garlington Run,Santa Maria,New Jersey,Mexico,2005-10-09,2005-10-10,30543,2005-10-14,Samsung,590.29,5,354.85,Service,292.56,1032.22
```

If you have too many files to pass on the command line and running it via xargs is too slow then here's another option:

```
awk -i inplace ... '
    BEGIN {
        while ( (getline line < ARGV[1]) > 0 ) {
            if ( line ~ /\.csv$/ ) {
                ARGV[ARGC] = line
                ARGC++
            }
        }
        ARGV[1] = ""
    }
    { the "real" script }
' <(ls)
```

The above reads the output of `ls` as an input file rather than as arguments, populates the array of arguments with those file names that end in `.csv`, and then operates on the files as if they had been passed as arguments on the command line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please see the new edits/test results that I have shown/updated in my question. I hope you'd be able to help me out.

Comment: Did you time just `ls *.csv | xargs awk ...` instead of doing it in batches? There's no benefit to passing subsets of files at a time to xargs AFAIK. The `find` and `for` loop approaches are calling awk one file at a time so those will be too slow.

Comment: `ls *.csv` again gives the same `Argument list too long` error. Same for your `awk` solution. I am trying to figure out how to get past that. Additionally I am trying to address how to write a for loop in for `11*.csv`, `12*.csv` and so on to avoid the error above. Still googling on that part.

Comment: Sorry, you can't use `*.csv` as an arg or it'll expand to your long list of file names, I should have said just `ls | xargs awk...` in a directory of just your .csvs. Or you could do `find . -name '*.csv' | xargs awk...`. I updated my question to show an alternative to using xargs as well. All the usual caveats of parsing the output of `ls` apply of course (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). A loop would just be `for i in {11..20}; do ls "$i"*.csv; done`.

Comment: If you don't mind can you please fill the "the real script" part also in your answer? I keep getting syntax errors. :(

Comment: ALl I'm saying is put that BEGIn section at the start of what you already have within `'...'`. SHow me what you tried.

Comment: perhaps `printf "%s\n" *.csv` instead of `ls *.csv`. Or `printf "%s\0" *.csv | xargs -0 awk ...`. As a shell builtin, `printf` should not give the `Argument list too long` error. And going through `xargs` should still be good enough...

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following two approaches:

```
$ find . -name \*.csv -type f ! -empty -exec \
  perl -spe 's/^/,/;
   $F //= $ARGV =~ s/\.csv$//r;
   s/^/$. == 1 ? "\n$C" : $F/e;
   undef $F, close ARGV if eof;
' -- -C="Customer" {} +
```

The second one makes use of Gnu sed features, in particular the the F command to get the filename and -s option to treat multiple files not as a single stream but  rather individually:

```
$ find . -name \*.csv -type f ! -empty -exec \
  sed -se 'F;1s/^/CUSTOMER,/' {} + |
  sed -E \
    -e 'N;s/.*\.csv(\nCUSTOMER,)/\1/;t' \
    -e 's/\.csv\n/,/;s/..//' \
;
```